# TemplateDoesNotExist - Creating a simple view

Tags: python, django

I have the following tree structure:

```
project/
  __init__.py
  app/
    __init__.py
    templates/
       home.html
       base.html
    settings.py
    urls.py
    views.py
    wsgi.py
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template.context import RequestContext
from django.template.loader import get_template

def home(request):
   context = RequestContext(request,
                           {'user': request.user})
   return render_to_response('templates/home.html',
                             context_instance=context)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', 'app.views.home', name='home'),

]
```

**relevant parts of settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app'
]

...

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Problem: When I run:

1. ./manage runserver
2. Navigate to 127.0.0.1:8000
3. It raises a `django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: templates/home.html`

I've tried different variations of the path as well as hardcoding the directory into the TEMPLATES dictionary in my settings file. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

This setup was fine. The problem was I was extending base.html in home.html

Like: `{% extends 'app/base.html' %}` when it needed to be {`% extends 'base.html' %}`